# SSIS Error code: 0xC0014009

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, interbase

How to solve problem run job SSIS by SQL Server Agent failed with error code : 0xC0014009.

My job ssis package transform data from source database interbase to target sql server for use ODBC. I found job failed

> Error: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
>   INTERBASE failed with error code 0XC0014009. There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

almost everyday but sometime job success.

When debugging I fix debug options `Run64BitRuntime => false` and job step properties I choose `32 bit runtime` already  but my job error code 0XC0014009 often.

On Windows 2012 R2, SQL server 2016

[image]

I set settings, DelayedValidation: True and all 32bit

[image]

Comment: so what were al lthose ODBC errors before transaction error in the log ?

Comment: maybe you can use ADO Provider of OLE DB provider (ibprovider.net) instead of ODBC

Comment: Are you using Firebird or Interbase? Don't tag both **they are not the same**, only tag what you use

Answer (score 0):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55179
Do you have the Attunity driver installed on the server?
Attunity 4.0 or 5.0? 32-bit or 64bit?
I had to have the 32-bit 5.0 driver installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same error code (0xC0014009) when my SSIS packages were failing after deployed to SQL Server 2017.  Was bashing my head against the wall, nothing worked, tried delayed validation, execute in 32-bit runtime, no success.

Background: My SSIS packages were very simple.  Copying data from a postgres RDS instance (using ODBC connector) to the SQL Server DB.  I couldn’t deploy the SSIS directly from my local machine’s VS because Windows Authentication doesn’t work (not on same network) and deployment is not allowed using SQL Server Authentication.  My deployment work around was copying the ispac file to the VM host, and then using SSMS (on the server) to deploy directly from the ispac.  Deployed fine, no problem right?  Wrong.  Deployed packages were failing with the 0xC0014009 error code, connection manager problem.  I think something was being lost in my process regarding the postgres ODBC connector.

My solution for this was following

- Downloaded the postgres driver on the VM, created an ODBC connector.  Everything tested fine, the connection worked to the RDS instance
- Installed visual studio on the VM host, with SSIS extension
- Copy SSIS solution from my local to VM host
- Loaded the SSIS solution in VS on the VM.  In the solution’s connection manager, switched the connection to the newly created ODBC connector, ran in visual studio as test.  Everything worked!
- Deployed the SSIS project from VM host’s visual studio, this time Windows Authentication worked obviously
- Now the packages work, being executed directly from SQL Server, no more 0xC0014009 errors