# SSIS Postgres odbc connection manager problem

Tags: ssis, connection, odbc

I'm trying to create an odbc connection manager for Postgres in SSIS. The dsn works and the list of tables comes up; however, when I select one of the tables and click Preview (or OK) I get the following. Any thoughts anyone...

[Connection manager error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuHJa.png)

Comment: If you successfully tested connection in ODBC Connection Manager to your server destination, try just to click on "column" tab on left side of your attached screenshot in question.

Comment: Can you please check the output or error windows once you close the dialogue to see if there is a more complete error message?  Also, have you tried writing it as a SQLCMD instead?

Comment: This is ultimately what worked. The DSN deployed did not match the valid DSN's on the SSIS server. Modifying the DSN reference in the Integration Services Catalog to use the local DSN worked.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063756/ssis-error-code-0xc0014009